# create Various <div> s in side the same image

Tags: jquery, html, image, dictionary

I want a create various `div`s inside the same image (background image).....my application is jQuery drag & drop application the dropping image(.PNG) shouldn't have drop some areas of an image
How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? What didn't work? What is it you want to do? (I realise that English may not be your native language, but if we can't understand your question, we can't help you).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify this question massively, it's impossible to tell what you are doing and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Use one div with the image as the background and then place droppable divs using absolute positioning wherever you need them in the container div.

Comment: Dear David Thomas, I want to divide an backgroung image into sevaral <div>s then i want to drag & drop another png images into that background but i have to program it some png images can drop specific areas. if we tried to drop wrong area(wrong <div>) it should be Revert former place